# Cannot start mysql on xampp Version 1.8.3

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I just to start installing Xampp and MySQL on my computer.
Then when I want to start the MySQL from the xampp control panel, it did not work.

The message in the control panel says "Attempting to start MySQL service.."
But the status won't change to green ( I start the Apache, and it works )

I have tried to re-install the MySQL and also Xampp, but it did not work.
Googling also not much help.

I have checked the MySQL service is running on port 3306.
Sometimes when I attempted to start the MySQL from the Xampp control panel, it said that there is MySQL occupying port 3306. However, when I changed the MySQL port in Xampp to 3307, the first problem occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port in the XAMPP Control Panel only tells XAMPP to monitor that port. You also need to change MySQL's configuration file (my.ini) to instruct MySQL to start on that port. The file can be found in xampp/mysql/bin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know this topic is old, but since the answer wasn't provided yet and here is the first place I reached in my attempt to solve the mystery of mySQL not starting, I'll go ahead and tell you what solved the problem for me in the end. I tried to make it easy to follow for inexperienced users too.

The obvious thing to check first is whether there's someone already occupying the port which mySQL is configured to use. By default, MySQL uses 3306. Make sure this is your case too. If you have the XAMPP Control Panel interface there's a button labeled Config for mySQL entry. A config file will open and you have to look for a line where the port value is set. Afterwards check whether something else is using that port. You can use a friendly app like "currports" or open a command line interface and type `netstat -an | findstr "3306"`.

The second thing to do is to check the error log. In the same XAMPP Control Panel interface click the 'Logs' button. See if mySQL logged any hints for your current problem's solution.

The last things I've tried, which is the one that solved my problem:

- Go to Start (the Windows icon, usually in the lower left corner)
- List item
- Write Services.msc into the search box (the only empty text box displayed in the pop up that appears when you press the Start button)
- A new window will appear.
- Look for 'mysql' in that list.

  - If column 'startup type' for the mysql entry says 'disabled' then that's your problem. 'Disabled' means it cannot be started by a program, only manually by you through this interface.
  - Double click on that entry and a configuration window appears. In the new window look for Startup Type and change it to 'Manual'
  - There's also a Start button there or you can go back to XAMPP interface and start it from there